# Compare first letter of strings in Matlab

Tags: matlab

I would like to see if the letter inputted by the user matches any of the words in a dictionary.

Could someone please help me do this? Thank you!

```
words = {'apple', 'banana', 'bee', 'salad', 'corn', 'elephant', 'pterodactyl'};

user_letter_input = input('Please enter the first letter of a word: ');

for i = words
    if (i starts with user_letter_input)
        disp(['Your new word is: ' i]);
    end
end
```

Comment: Check out `strncmpi`: http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/strncmpi.html

Comment: Also, your 'end' is missing for the if clause

Comment: I agree with @em1382: Matlab's built-in function with strings (`strcmp`, `strfind`, `strncmpi`, `strcmpi` and so on) are more robust than the straight comparison `x==y`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use:

```
if(i{1}(1) == user_letter_input)
```

Comment: so you're saying: `if (i(1) == user_letter_input)`?

Comment: Sorry, you need to dereference the cell first. I have updated my answer to account for that.

Answer (score 0):

Here's a different, admittedly more hackish approach:

```
w = char(words); %// convert to 2D char array, padding with spaces
result = find(w(:,1)==user_letter_input); %// test equality with first column
```

`result` will be a vector with the indices of all matching words. For example,

```
words = {'apple', 'banana', 'bee', 'salad', 'corn', 'elephant', 'pterodactyl'};
user_letter_input = 'b'
```

will give

```
result =
     2
     3
```